# How to install gem 'meta-where'? I am getting error while "bundle install"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Rails 3.2.9 version

My gem file

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.9'
gem 'feedzirra'
gem "meta_where"

gem 'sqlite3'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

And i am getting error like below while bundle install. How to install meta-where gem?

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "arel":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    arel (3.0.2)

  In Gemfile:
    meta_where (~> 1.0.4) ruby depends on
      arel (~> 2.0.7) ruby

Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meta_where is for rails 2 - you're using rails 3.

The meta_where GitHub page https://github.com/ernie/meta_where says you should use squeel instead https://github.com/ernie/squeel